# Read sharepoint list anonymous using graph api

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We need to access a sharepoint list (readonly) from a public web site (wordpress) using ajax. Whats the best approach?

It seems like the graph api would give us all the data we need, but that would require a user. In case of using it from the public web site, we don't have a user.

From my understanding there are two options:

1. Create a API application (WebApi or similar) and access the graph based on some service account.
2. Configure anonyoms access directly in microsoft graph. Not sure if this is possible?

In case of option 2, I guess we would need to provide some token when accessing the graph api. How would this token be created?

Maybe there are other options to reading this list from the client?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Comment: so you want your Wodrpress website to access the list from SharePoint? just use REST, why are you so worried?

Comment: Because we need to be authenticated to access the list via the rest api

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to be authenticated to read the list, you should use the Secure Store to guarantee the access to a resource in SharePoint, the credentials will be securely stored in SharePoint and the client accessing the resource in SharePoint will be granted access.